# SQL*Plus syntax doesn't connect via LDAP within SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, ldap, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, tnsnames

I have a tricky question which I haven't find how to solve it yet. I use LDAP for ORACLE DB connections, on hundreds of DBs and there are no errors when I manually create connections in SQL Developer.

But, if I use SQL*Plus syntax within SQL Developer to switch between different connections: *CONNECT username/password@connect_identifier*, I get a "*connection failed message*".
The reason is that it doesn't respect anymore the order defined in **sqlnet.ora** with (LDAP, tnsnames, ezconnect) and it goes directly to the **tnsnames.ora** file.
If I define the connect_identifier in **tnsnames.ora**, it connects successfully, but I want to use LDAP, because it's always maintained directly by DBA.
TNS_ADMIN is defined correctly and works properly.

Also, if I open a cmd screen and use sqlplus username/password@connect_identifier, it works via LDAP.
So only SQL Developer doesn't want to use LDAP via CONNECT syntax.

I tried on different machines and with different SQL Developer releases, depending on what is installed on the machines, from 3.0.0.4 to 17.3.2, but I met the same behavior.

On 17.3.2, where there is also the JDBC THIN connection option, I've seen it automatically tries to transform into a jdbc thin connection string, and of course, it fails:
`USER = user
URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@connect_identifier.world:1521/connect_identifier.world
Error Message = IO Error: Unknown host specified`

Why this behavior within SQL Developer and is there any way to force the **CONNECT** syntax to use **LDAP** instead of **tnsnames.ora**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an URL like this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://ldap_server.your.domain.com:389/cn=OracleContext,dc=your,dc=domain,dc=com/SID
```

Replace `ldap_server.your.domain.com` with your LDAP server address and `SID` with the database alias.

In SQL Developer you should be able to select LDAP base alias resolution:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I have no problem in creating the New Connection manually, I can use both LDAP & TNS connection type, and they both resolve LDAP without errors, what I really want is to use a script which makes the same select on 100 different instances like:

`CONNECT user/pass@conn_1;
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
select * from table ;
CONNECT user/pass@conn_2;
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
select * from table ;` and so on...